# Javascript: Modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button

```
<button class="modalInput" rel="#prompt" onClick="params(1,2,'test','test2');">User input</button>
```

A JavaScript call:

```
<script>
  function params(a,b,c,d) {
  var catid = a;
  var id = b;
  var text1 = c;
  var text2 = d;
}
```

A Modal window:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({


<div class="modal" id="prompt">
<form>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Question:</td><td><input value=text1 name="question" maxlength="80" size="40"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Answer:</td><td><input value=text2 name="answer" maxlength="40" size="40"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="catid" value=catid />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value=id />
<script>
alert (text1);
document.getElementByName('question').value = text1;
</script>
```

I thought I could just do the script part at the end, but that doesnt Work... So, what do I do wrong? The last script part is not executed at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that declaring a variable with "var" makes it local. These 2 lines of code don't make much sense:

```
<input type="hidden" name="catid" value=catid />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value=id />
```

Since it's plain HTML. You should set their value with javascript.

Edit: So from what I understand, you want the params() function to set the form values. You can do that like that (plain JS, with jQuery it's even simpler):

```
function params(a,b,c,d) {
  var catid = getElementsByName("catid")[0];
  catid.value = a;
  //same for the other 3
}
```

Comment: Well - those two fields should be used in the form, I want to mail the entire form, with hidden fields to myself on submit..

But if the "var" is locale, how can i declare them global so I can use them?

Comment: I edited the answer, see if that's what you need :) also, note that it would be a bit cleaner with getElementById(), provided you will set the id attribute on your hidden inputs